# List of JavaScript top-level objects (window, document, Notification, XMLHttpRequest, etc)

Tags: javascript

Where can I find a list of top-level JavaScript objects?

What is (if not "top-level") the correct way to reference these objects?

If you `alert()` the object in a modern browser it should be defined.

```
alert(window);//[object Window]
alert(document);//[object HTMLDocument]
alert(Notification);//function Notification() {[native code]}
alert(XMLHttpRequest);//function XMLHttpRequest() {[native code]}
```

No frameworks.

Comment: How do you define `top-level` objects?

Comment: @MaxZoom They must alert something such as demonstrated in my question (e.g. `alert(Notification);`).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Answer (score 3):

These are called global objects (as they are on the global scope). You can see them by opening up console in Chrome/Firefox and typing "window" or console.log(window).